# CakePHP 3 - Event on Model->link(...)

Tags: events, cakephp-3.0, models, join

I am working on an application management panel, with `Users` and `Apps`. I would like to log the changes (add / edit / delete) to both Apps and Users. This I realised using a custom Behavior, using the `afterSave()` and `afterDelete()` callbacks.

Note that Apps `hasMany` Users and Users `hasMany` Apps, with a `apps_users` join table. I created models for `Apps` and `Users`.

However, I would also like to log the links between Apps and Users (the permissions). When permissions are given, a link between a user and an app is created using `Apps->Users->link($app, [$user])`.

**Question: How to attach an callback to a `$...->link(...)` call?**

As far as I can tell there is not regular callback for it, like there is for `save()` and `delete()`

Comment: `link` and `unlink` should trigger callbacks on the join table, not the `Apps` or `Users` directly.

Comment: I gave it a try and that worked. The point is never create models for join tables, it normally is not necessary.

Comment: When a join table is "only" a join table, there's no need to create a model for it. But when it needs to do more, it's nice that the option is there for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing my own questions when I noticed this.

The solution would be to create table objects for the link table and add `afterSave` and `afterDelete` events for those tables. A behaviour could be created that is attached to those link table objects to reuse the logic.